# Play sound on mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, alert

I have a script running in the background and sends me an alert every few minutes. I want the alert to be in the form of a beep.

Question: How can I play a beep in mac terminal?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

`printf \\a` and `osascript -e beep` play the default alert sound, but they are silent if the alert volume is set to zero. `printf \\a` is also silent if an audible bell is disabled.

You could also use afplay or say:

```
afplay /System/Library/Sounds/Funk.aiff
say done
```

There are more sound effect files in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ScreenReader.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Sounds/`.

Comment: I was using say till now, afplay did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Sweet! You can use `say -v ?` (in Yosemite, at least) to get a list of voices installed -- I had several! Here's a little script to say what you want in every available voice: `for i in $(say -v \? | awk '{print $1;}'); do echo $i; say -v $i "Build terminated\!"; done`

Comment: In macOS Catalina, I had to use `say -v '?'` with single quotes because of zsh.

Answer (score 23):

The simplest way is the use a bell
`echo -e "\a"`

Comment: Didn't work for me. Do I need a package?

Comment: What version of OS X are you on? Also, check your terminal emulator's settings, and make sure you don't have bell disabled.

Comment: Ah! Terminal sounds were not enabled. Also, is there a decent bell/alert compared to the dull thud sound this command makes?

Comment: I use iTerm2 myself, which uses growl (so bells go to growl), via growl I add another sound to iTerm2 alerts. Yeah, kind of round-about.

Comment: Ohk, I will use that setup as a last resort ;)

Comment: You can change the sound played in System Preferences. The sound used by terminal is just the system wide alert sound which you can find in the Sound prefs.

Comment: @Tonny quite valid, and I should have recalled to mention that. I don't use that method as I wish to tell the difference between the command line and the rest of the system beeping at me.

Comment: @demure Ideally me too, but I run so few scripts (on OSX) that I never bothered to setup something up like that. I just enable "Visible bell" to get that little extra feedback.

Comment: discovered that echo ^G and tput bel  have the same effect.

Comment: Not sure why this warranted a down vote :/

Comment: What does the `-e` option do? It is not listed in the man pages

Comment: A way to make a command-line alias for one (without escape sequences) is: alias beep='tput bel'

Comment: `-e` is a non-POSIX extension supported by some shells, e.g., `bash`. Instead, prefer to use the portable `printf` command, e.g., `printf '\a'`. Still, the most portable solution is `tput bel` because the terminal may use something other than or in addition to Control-G.

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to `echo ^G`. But you don't literally type the `^G`. Instead, type `ctrl+v, ctrl+g`, which will appear as `echo ^G`.

Comment: @tmanok On a mac? `ctrl+G` by itself does not do anything for me on a mac.

Comment: Oh? It does on Sierra and Yosemite for me.... Odd

Comment: But it isn't working on my 10.6 machine- maybe some of my CLI Tools or Homebrew is screwing with it. I'll retract my comment, apologies.

Answer (score 6):

Hear and pick

```
ls /System/Library/Sounds/ | awk '{print $1}' | while read sound; do printf "using $sound...\n"; afplay /System/Library/Sounds/$sound; sleep 0.5; done

ls /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ScreenReader.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Sounds/ | awk '{print $1}' | while read sound; do printf "using $sound...\n"; afplay /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ScreenReader.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Sounds/$sound; sleep 0.5; done
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful to try out the different sounds

Answer (score 5):

> `tput bel` works in most shells.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6256541/173497) on a related Stack Overflow question:

- [bash - How to make the hardware beep sound in Mac OS X 10.6 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127977/how-to-make-the-hardware-beep-sound-in-mac-os-x-10-6)

Answer (score 0):

There's one more way that can be useful in cases like, let's say you forgot to set the alert and in the middle of the process, and on Iterm. Simply `Cmd` + `Option` + `A` while in terminal screen lets you have a notification in the end of the process.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I found this useful, why the downvotes? It really does add to the other answers.